# Excluding SKUs from Price Promotions

Tags: promotions

How do I exclude certain SKUs from Price Promotions? (Category Rules or Shopping Cart Rules)
I do have Amnesty Special Promotions Extension. I just have 3 items that are special order only and I want to excluded them from all promotions.

Thanks

Comment: What's your version of Magento? There are bugs in certain 1.8 and 1.9 versions relating to this.

Answer (score 3):

First, edit the `SKU` attribute:

`CATALOG >> ATTRIBUTES >> MANAGE ATTRIBUTES`

Change the setting `Used for Promo Conditions` to `YES`.

Now, when you create a new promo rule, under `CONDITIONS` make sure you choose `SKU`. You can then click on `is` and change it to `is not one of` - from there you can add the SKUs you wish to exclude from the promo.

Apply the rule and you should be good to go (assuming you don't have other issues getting promos working properly).

Comment: I'm still having issues. I have: If an item is FOUND in the cart with ANY of these conditions true: SKU IS NOT 1338, 1340, 1341

Comment: Make sure the rules are being applied. I suggest reviewing: http://www.solvingmagento.com/quick-tip-magento-catalog-price-rules-dont-work/